# How to use "QAndroidApplication::runOnAndroidMainThread" to change color of status- and navigation bar?

Tags: android, qt, qml, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

I am still very new to Qt and qml and struggle with getting the color of the statusbar and navigationbar changed on deployed andriod apps with qtquick.

I have found that it is possible to change the color of the statusbar via  QtAndroid::runOnAndroidThread, but that seems to not work for more recent Qt Versions.

I have found out that this code is probably the one to use now (https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qnativeinterface-qandroidapplication.html#runOnAndroidMainThread) :

```
QAndroidApplication::runOnAndroidMainThread(const std::function<QVariant ()> &runnable, const QDeadlineTimer timeout = QDeadlineTimer::Forever)
```

with #include .

But unfortunately there aren't any examples I could find on the internet how and where in the code this function is used. And more specifically, how would I use this code to change the color of the status- and navigationbar?

I would really appreciate help here.

Answer (score 0):

Example: showing toast message (running this not in UI-thread will cause exception)

```
QString message = "Hello from Toast!";
const int duration = 1; // 0 - short, 1 - long
auto interface = qApp->nativeInterface<QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication>();
interface->runOnAndroidMainThread([message, duration, interface] {
    auto javaMessage = QJniObject::fromString(message);
    auto toast = QJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
        "android/widget/Toast",
        "makeText",
        "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;",
        interface->context(),
        javaString.object(),
        jint(duration)
    );
    toast.callMethod<void>("show");
});
```